# Azure Websites WebMatrix Add Existing File Greyed

Tags: azure, webmatrix

I have a dotnet nuke website hosted on the new Azure Websites Preview. I want to add a new logo image. I clicked the WebMatrix Icon and WebMatrix 2.0 was installed. I can see a list of my websites files in a tree view down the left side. I navigate to the images folder. I want to click the "Add Existing" icon from the "Files" section of the top ribbon menu but it's greyed out. Can anyone please advise why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick question:  Are you in the remote view of Webmatrix?

If so, unfortunately, we don't yet support uploading existing files from your computer.  The easiest way to get a file uploaded would probably to click the download button up top and download your site locally.  You can then make whatever changes you like to your local site and publish them back up.

Also, we greatly appreciate feedback on our product and any suggestions on how we can improve it.  The best way to get your ideas implemented is to [make a suggestion on uservoice](http://webmatrix.uservoice.com/).